# H10 "App crashed" error on Heroku, but it is not very descriptive

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I keep getting the below error:

```
2018-09-05T21:53:30.439186+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=still-mesa-69894.herokuapp.com request_id=51732ef5-7b89-4629-900e-8a73c927d07f fwd="137.146.137.3
0" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-09-05T21:53:30.908139+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=still-mesa-69894.herokuapp.com request_id=32608dfd-2314-48e6-9696-8fa2fcd02d13 fwd="13
7.146.137.30" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

This is my package.json.

```
{
  "name": "myfinalproject",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:1337",
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^1.4.2",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "mapbox-gl": "^0.47.0",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.1",
    "mdi-material-ui": "^5.2.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.2.6",
    "morgan": "^1.9.0",
    "node-geocoder": "^3.22.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-geolocation": "^1.0.4",
    "react-mapbox-gl": "^3.8.0",
    "react-navigation": "^2.9.3",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "react": "react-scripts start",
    "dev": "npm run server | react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.11.2",
    "npm": "6.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.17.5"
  }
}
```

I have these in my server.js

```
const express = require('express');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
var port = server.address().port;

// res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 1337);
```

I think there's error with the '/' route, but no idea why. It works on my localhost. This is a react app. I am a first timer on Heroku. I use PC Windows, not a Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why are you accessing port inside app.get method, but here is what you have to do to fix the issue.

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

//Assign port like this
const port = process.env.PORT || 1337;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("App is running on port ", this.address().port);
});
```

Check this [Heroku official help guide](https://help.heroku.com/P1AVPANS/why-is-my-node-js-app-crashing-with-an-r10-error) for more details.

PS: I replaced normal function with arrow function. But if you still want to use normal function you can.